Twill3 CMS: How to create a Block via Component-Form-Builder which works as Repeater of another Block
I would like to create an block (CardContainer) in Twill 3 via form builder component which works as Repeater of CardItem-Blocks (equally built as component). Unfortunately I'm rather confused with the whole repeater typology (repeater, inlinerepeater, json-repeater) and the mixture of block building method in twill (formbuilder, formview, directives).
The CardItem block to be repeated ist built this way and works as it should as stand-alone block:
...
public function getForm(): Form
    {
        return Form::make([ 

            Medias::make()->name('image')->label(twillTrans('Card-Bild')),

            Browser::make()->name('href')->label(twillTrans('Card-Link'))->modules($this->browsableClasses)->max(1),

            Input::make()->name('title')->label(twillTrans('Card-Titel'))->translatable(),

            Checkbox::make()->name('overlay')->label(twillTrans('Titel überlagern')),

            Wysiwyg::make()->name('text')->label(twillTrans('Card-Text'))->translatable()->toolbarOptions($this->wysiwygOptions)->browserModules($this->browsableClasses),
            
        ]);
    }
...

How to build the component for the CardContainer repeater block. This is where I get stuck:
...
 public function getForm(): Form
    {
        return Form::make([ 

            InlineRepeater::make()->name('cards') 

                ->fields([

                    (new CardItem)->repeater('cards'), // does not work

                ]) 
            //InlineRepeater::make()->name('card')->type('blikk-carditem') // does not work
            //Repeater::make()->name('cards')->type('text') // does not work either

        ]);
    }
...

Probably I got the whole concept wrong - any help appreciated. Thanks.

For anyone interested, I got an answer in the github discussion https://github.com/area17/twill/discussions/2343:
There is no way to use a block as an InlineRepeater field - instead you have to repeat the form fields of that block directly:
 public function getForm(): Form
    {
        return Form::make([
            InlineRepeater::make()
                ->name('cards')
                ->max(3)
                ->fields([
                    Medias::make()->name('image')->label(twillTrans('Card-Bild')),
                    Browser::make()->name('href')->label(twillTrans('Card-Link'))->modules($this->browsableClasses)->max(1),
                    Input::make()->name('title')->label(twillTrans('Card-Titel'))->translatable(),
                    Checkbox::make()->name('overlay')->label(twillTrans('Titel überlagern')),
                    Wysiwyg::make()->name('text')->label(twillTrans('Card-Text'))->translatable()->toolbarOptions($this->wysiwygOptions)->browserModules($this->browsableClasses),
                ])
        ]);
    }

